# Limit OpenVPN bandwith

Tags: linux, openvpn, qos

Is it possible to configure OpenVPN server to limit bandwidth use per user? Limiting either maximum speed (etc. to 100kb/s) or total downloaded/uploaded data per month is

Answer (score 2):

You could check if the `--shaper` open fits your needs. If you need something more complex, you could use linux `tc` to set speeds per IP.

Also, you could set up OpenVPN with a Radius backend for authentication and accounting.

Comment: when I use `openvpn --sharper 250000` it doesn't work for me and show the error `Unrecognized option or missing or extra parameter(s) in [CMD-LINE]:1: sharper (2.4.4)`. how can I use shaper??